# Comment voting scrolls to top of page

Tags: bug, comment-voting

This doesn't happen very often, but it's happened enough that I'm sure it's more than me imagining it. Sometimes when I click to vote up a comment, the page will scroll all the way to the top. The URL has an empty `#` fragment appended to it. Has anyone else noticed this?

Edit: this is very weird. I had originally thought that it was only happening if I tried to upvote a comment just as the page had loaded, perhaps while the JS was still being parsed and evaluated. But there have been multiple times now when this happens long after the page has loaded. In fact, it has even happened that I've upvoted one comment and it works properly, and *then upvoted a second comment on the same page* and it scrolls to the top.

Windows 10, Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Still happening in Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Sounds like either you clicked the upvote before the page was done loading, or there was some js error that prevented the event from being bound to the upvote button.

Comment: Browser configuration and OS version, please?

Comment: It would be great if you also showed us JS console logs from the next time you reproduce this bug.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog The log is empty.